# Pass value from ObjectDataSource object level to ASP .NET Control

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm working with ObjectDataSource and FormView control.

In ObjectDataSource I have a type specified, and a method that performs Insert operation. However, once Insert is done, I would like to redirect the user to other page, and I need ID of newly created/persisted object.

So in FormView:

```
OnItemInserted="OnFormItemInserted"
```

handler I need to access that ID. But how to pass that id gracefully from ObjectDataSource level? I could use

```
HttpContext.Current.Items
```

inside ObjectDataSource handling object, but I don't like it, as my handling type do not know anything about ASP .NET (separation of concerns?).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something simple like this:

### In your Data object

Update your insert method configured in the `ObjectDataSource` control to return the generated ID:

```
public int Insert(string firstName, int lastname)
{
    // return the ID generated by the insert command
    return 4;
}
```

### ASPX code behind

And that's it, in your page where you are handling the `Inserted` event:

```
protected void ods_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    var res = e.ReturnValue.ToString();
    this.lblMessage.Text = res;
    // add your cool additional logic and redirect stuff
}
```